# Создание анимации с помощью Artistanimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Я хочу анимировать картинки, созданные с помощью `networkx`, средствами `matplotlib`.
Код выглядит примерно так:

```
fig = plt.figure()
graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_nodes_from(used)
for node in g:
    for value in g[node]:
        graph.add_edge(node, value)
positions = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw(graph, positions)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, positions, font_size=14, font_color="black")
myimages = []
for i in range(0, len(used)+1):
    new_image = graph
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(new_image, positions, used[:i], node_color="red", edgecolors="black")
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(new_image, positions, used[i:], node_color="white", edgecolors="black")
    myimages.append(new_image)
an = anim.ArtistAnimation(fig, myimages)
an.save('name.gif')
```

Однако, видимо, объекты типа `nx.Digraph()` не могут быть анимированы, поскольку вылетает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

Как мне грамотно сохранить атрибуты для дальнейшей отрисовки, чтобы можно было создать анимацию?

Видимо, нужно как-то создать `Artist`- объекты, чтобы потом их использовать для создания анимации.